# Core data auto save vs manual save

Tags: ios, core-data

When using core data for my project, I only manually save the context when I'm adding new data.  Any other edits to data, such as title change or delete, I've been relying on auto-save.  However, I noticed that if I make an edit and my app crashes, on reload those changes I made prior to the crash don't appear.  Because of this I decided to manually save the context after every edit.  Is this bad practice?  When I first started using core data, I was under the impression that you want to auto-save instead of manual saving.  In the iOS Standford lectures about core data, the professor recommends relying on auto-save and to implement manual saving when debugging.

I do my manual saves as follows:

```
-(void) updateSaveContext
{
    [self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if(success)
        {
            NSLog(@" NEW FILE SAVED");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"FAIL TO SAVE");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, your NSManagedObjectContext is a scratchpad. All changes you make are done on that scratchpad. When you order your UIManagedDocument to save. It will validate all rules you've set in your object model. If one of them fails it will not save it and in the logging you will find a Cocoa Error coming from the Core Data framework.
Usually it is a missing required Attribute of an Entity, or a missing required Relation ship that is invalid.

What Cocoa error do you get?